# Rstudio server not running on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, google-compute-engine, rstudio-server

Why does "rstudio-server start" not work??

At this point, I could not find any helpful answer even on stackoverflow.
I cross-checked that the below steps 1-5 are sufficient for installing Rstudio Server on Ubuntu from the following blog-posts:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-rstudio-server-on-ubuntu-server/
http://www.joeroe.eu/blog/2015/08/rstudio-server-on-a-google-compute-engine-instance/
https://gist.github.com/rweald/4321052

Here's what I did:

**1. Create Google Cloud VM**

Google Cloud Compute Engine > Create VM Instance (on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

**2. Installing R**

```
sudo nano /etc/sources.list
```

enter:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```

get public key for ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-key adv —keyserver keys.gnupg.net —recv-key 381BA480
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base libapparmor1
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

**3. Installing Rstudio Server**

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-1.0.143-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.0.143-amd64.deb
```

**4. Open port 8787 in Google Cloud firewall**

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-rstudio --allow tcp:8787
```

> Remark: I did verify that the port 8787 is open:
> gcloud compute firewall-rules list
> NAME                    NETWORK  SRC_RANGES    RULES                         SRC_TAGS  TARGET_TAGS
> allow-rstudio           default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:8787                                allow-rstudio

**5. Verify Rstudio Server**

> No response: http://:8787 >> browser is hanging
>
> No response: sudo rstudio-server verify-installation >> command executes, no message
>
> No response: sudo rstudio-server restart >> no running process to restart ("rsession: no process found")
>
> No response: sudo rstudio-server start >> command executes, no message

Thanks for any thoughtful help why RStudio Server is not running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *created* a firewall rule, but you didn't *apply* it to any VM, so the port is still not open on that VM, and thus, you cannot reach your server.

When you create a firewall rule, add a tag to it as [per the docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules):

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-rstudio-server \
    --allow tcp:8787 \
    --target-tags rstudio-server
```

Then, [add the `rstudio-server` tag](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/add-remove-network-tags#adding_new_tags_to_vm_instances) to the VM(s):

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags [INSTANCE_NAME] --tags rstudio-server
```

Then try accessing the UI on your server again.

---

That said, you should really consider using an [encrypted SSH tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely) to connect to your GCE VM securely instead, to avoid eavesdropping on your data while it is in transit from your computer to your GCE VM and back, or risk [MITM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) which can intercept your password and take over your server, since you're using plain-text HTTP to access your server.

Comment: Dear Misha, you made my day. This is the exact solution that made it work instantly. Thank you soo much. I will now try to follow your advice on encrypted ssh tunnel.

Comment: @SoKalbi — please note that if you do use the SSH tunnel approach, then *do not* also open the port in the firewall (i.e., remove the tag and delete the firewall rule). These are mutually-exclusive solutions: the easy way (via port/firewall) and the secure way (via SSH tunnel).

Comment: Thanks @Misha following your advice i removed the tag but then the  rstudio server is not accessible then except through the localhost. how do I make it accessible again without an SSL certificate?

Comment: @SoKalbi — the SSH tunnel approach I linked to in my answer does not require an SSL certificate; can you clarify what you mean? If you want to access it directly via plain-text unencrypted HTTP protocol (insecure), you can add the tag to the VM again to open that same port in the firewall.

Comment: Sorry @Misha for not being clear. I think I use the ssh tunnel by "gcloud compute ssh <instance name>" to connect to the rstudio server through local host, right? I never used http...

Comment: @SoKalbi — using the SSH tunnel, you connect via HTTP to localhost, i.e., `http://localhost:<port>/`; it will not be accessible (by design) via a public IP, because that would be insecure. If anyone else wants to access your server, they also need to create such a tunnel (which means you need to give them SSH access to your server). If you want to make it secure for everyone, see http://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/access-and-security.html for more details, but that's beyond the scope of this question.